# PHP how to combine array and create new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have 3 arrays like this :

```
$first = array(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 66
    [2] => 15
)

$second = array
(
    [0] => append
    [1] => prepend
    [2] => append
)

$third = array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 1
)
```

Now I want to combine these 3 array and create new **SINGLE** array like this :
I want to get value from each array and combine it into one.

```
$new_array = array(

    [0] = array (
        'page'=>13,
        'position'=>'append'
        'priority'=>'2'
    )
    [1] = array (
        'page'=>66,
        'position'=>'prepend'
        'priority'=>'4'
    )
    [2] = array (
        'page'=>15,
        'position'=>'append'
        'priority'=>'1'
    )
)
```

How to do this ?

Comment: You are taking page from the first array, position from the second, and priority from the third. What's wrong with a simple `foreach()`? Use one of the arrays as guide to get the index (`foreach (array_keys($first) as $k) {`) and then build the new array element from `[ 'page' => $first[$k], 'position' => $second[$k], 'priority' => $third[$k] ]`. Then append the element to the growing result array.

Comment: Since each element has 3 indices, you can do a `for()` loop, reference `$first[$i]`, `$second[$i]` and `$third[$i]` and construct a new array. Did you try anything? You need to show your attempt and any issues you're facing; Stackoverflow is not a free coding service

Comment: Okay @lserni Worked for me.
I got it.

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: @abracadaver , No I am on Diwali Vacation. 
Here in India , Celebrating Diwali Festival

Comment: I meant, you have answers, if one solved your issue then mark it accepted.

Comment: @abracadaver
Well , 1st comment in my question , and All the answers are correct , so I upvoted all of them.
I have implemented the highest vote answer in my project , So For mark accepted , I will go with the highest vote on answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [array_map()](https://php.net/array_map) to traverse multiple arrays(of the same length) and build a new array from them, item by item:

```
$first = array(13, 66, 15);
$second = array('append', 'prepend', 'append');
$third = array(2, 4, 1);

print_r(
    array_map(
        function($page, $position, $priority) {
            return compact('page', 'position', 'priority');
        },
        $first,
        $second, 
        $third
    )
);
```

Though in this case with a trivial structure foreach() might be an alternative.

**Edit:** Version 2. Some might argue that this is worse because of readability and hence code maintainability. Thanks to AbraCadaver

```
$keys = ['page', 'position', 'priority'];

// Note: The order in $keys and array_map() arguments must be the same
// On the other hand you only need to type the keys once and it's easy
// to change the number of arguments :)

print_r(
    array_map(
        function(...$args) use ($keys) {
            return array_combine($keys, $args);
        },
        $first,
        $second, 
        $third
    )
);
```

**Edit:** Version 3. Using slightly more modern PHP (7.4) with arrow functions:

```
print_r(
    array_map(
        fn(...$args) => array_combine($keys, $args),
        $first,
        $second, 
        $third
    )
);
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yeah, some like it, some dont :). But I thought it would save some typing repeating the keys in this case. One could probably take it one step further using your $keys approach and the function args. I guess. But it's nice with some readability too :)..

Answer (score 2):

Just map each element of each array and return an array with the keys:

```
$result = array_map(function($f, $s, $t) {
                        return ['page'=>$f, 'position'=>$s, 'priority'=>$t];
                    }, $first, $second, $third);
```

Or define the keys outside of the function and combine with each element:

```
$keys = ['page', 'position', 'priority'];
$result = array_map(function($f, $s, $t) use($keys) {
                        return array_combine($keys, [$f, $s, $t]);
                    }, $first, $second, $third);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have same column, you can do it like this

```
$first = [13,66,15];
$second = ['append','prepend','append'];
$third = [2,4,1];

foreach($first as $v => $i){
    $new_array[] = [
    'page' => $i,
    'position' => $second[$v],
    'priority' => $third[$v],
    ];
}

print_r($new_array);
```

this is the result

[image]